# "There was an error retrieving this Add-on's configuration"

Tags: looker-studio

I'm working on a connector. I have the following error when I'm trying to deploy my script:

`There was an error retrieving this Add-on's configuration.`

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the code / knowing what you are trying to do.

Several possibilities:

- `getConfig` is not defined or returns wrong values.
- `getConfig` has an error.

Comment: I have the same issue Minhaz. Although I love the idea of developers such as myself being able to write a custom connector and I will admit the documentation is pretty good on that side I however am quite frustrated at the moment that you are not providing better debugging messages. The documentation for debugging on the other hand (https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/debug) is also not enough explanatory for beginners. For instance, how do I enable extended error messages? How do I log relevant execution data? How do I use isAdminUser()? And so on.

Comment: Sorry the error messaging isn't delivering your expected results. This is good feedback. Have you tried the error handling and messages guide here: https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/error-handling ? One limitation is that you can only show custom error messages for *Connector internal error*. For "Connector external error" (such as the one mentioned in the original question), Data Studio will show its own error message.